# CoreLocation kCLErrorDomain error 5

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-location, clregion

I subclassed a `CLRegion` to support Polygons via overriding `containsCoordinate:` to use ray casting logic instead of the original distance crunching logic. The subclass is initialized via the normal method (`initCircularRegionWithCenter:radius:identifier:`), then `CLLocationCoordinate2d`s are added as `NSValue`s to a mutable array. These coordinates are used during the ray casting logic.

As soon as I try to use the CLRegion subclass, I am confronted with a ton of errors in my application logic, as well as the following error:

```
2013-07-18 16:46:44.515 Geofencing[4816:907] (identifier 6C11CBAF-3EE4-4257-9D75-9724F4349B5D) <+39.86605072,-75.54420471> radius 186.54m: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 5.)"
```

I also tried a different subclass that does not modify any methods but adds a method for reading metadata from an NSDictionary. I was confronted with the same error.

What is going on? Is subclassing CLRegion feasible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 7 CoreLocation: region monitoring fails on the first time after location services are authorised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404620/ios-7-corelocation-region-monitoring-fails-on-the-first-time-after-location-ser)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but I have found the solution to my issue. A `kCLErrorDomain` code/error of 5 denotes that you have tried to **monitor more than 20** `CLRegions`. In my case, both subclasses were guilty of monitoring more than 20 regions.

Comment: See other answers; error code 5 does not denote this, it appears to be a 'catch all' code for various error conditions.

Comment: does not *only* denote this. You do get this message if you try to add > 20 beacons.

Comment: Happens to me as well, adding 25 beacons returns 5 aforementioned error codes.

Comment: what is the solution to remove monitor region? I tried with stopMonitoringForRegion which i registered, but didn't work for.

Comment: you can get this while monitoring 1 region, this shouldn't be the accepted answer to ```CoreLocation kCLErrorDomain error 5```, even if it was the answer for the OP, perhaps update the question so other people don't end up here

Comment: Can you tell how can we define if `CLBeaconRegion` is nil ?

Comment: Maybe it is because you forgot to turn on your Bluetooth

Comment: I can confirm that more than 20 regions trigger this issue, and is actually when the uuuid (last hex unit) is more than 19 (UInt8(19))

Answer (score 11):

It also happens if you:

stop monitoring a region

```
[self.manager stopMonitoringForRegion:region];
```

and request the state for all monitored regions shortly afterwards:

```
for (CLRegion *region in self.manager.monitoredRegions) {
    [self.manager requestStateForRegion:region];
}
```

you will get the kCLErrorDomain 5 because IOS seems to have disabled the monitoring for that region, but has not yet removed it from the monitoredRegions array

```
monitoringDidFailForRegion CLCircularRegion (identifier:'Home', center:<...>, radius:102.00m) The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 5.)
monitoredRegion: CLCircularRegion (identifier:'Home', center:<...>, radius:102.00m)
monitoredRegion: CLBeaconRegion (identifier:'BeaconHome', uuid:<..., major:(null), minor:(null))
monitoredRegion: CLCircularRegion (identifier:'D...', center:<...>, radius:101.00m)
monitoredRegion: CLCircularRegion (identifier:'W...', center:<..>, radius:51.00m)
```

to work around that problem, do something like this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"monitoringDidFailForRegion %@ %@",region, error.localizedDescription);
    for (CLRegion *monitoredRegion in manager.monitoredRegions) {
        NSLog(@"monitoredRegion: %@", monitoredRegion);
    }
    if ((error.domain != kCLErrorDomain || error.code != 5) &&
        [manager.monitoredRegions containsObject:region]) {
        NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
            region, error.localizedDescription];
        [AlertView alert:@"monitoringDidFailForRegion" message:message];
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly happened to me. Would be nice if solution is just showing up alert.

Comment: After googling around, I found this http://www.cocoanetics.com/2014/05/radar-monitoring-clregion-immediately-after-removing-one-fails/ .. It works.. Yayy!!.

Comment: What can I do to avoid this error in the same scenario? I need to stop monitoring a region and start monitoring another region at the same time.

Answer (score 7):

Also: if you're testing with iBeacons, you can't use the iOS simulator.

Answer (score 4):

It is also possible to get this error code back when your latitude and longitude values don't make sense. (I'd transposed them, for example, and was vexed by this error for a while.)

Comment: How long I searched for the issue and found out that I also transposed them :-D Thanks!

Comment: that is helpful, I'm noticing this on a user's device who is seemingly unable to get accurate gps

Answer (score 3):

This error could also rise up if added `CLRegion` is `nil`.

Comment: That too, It's probably a blanket error code. Lazy apple engineers xD

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is still struggling with this then take a look here:

In my case, I had to call `requestAlwaysAuthorization` just before calling `startMonitoring` and it worked like charm!

```
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

let currRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: LAT, longitude: LONG, radius: 100, identifier: "MyLocation")
currRegion.notifyOnEntry = true

locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
```

Btw, I would love to thank https://shrikar.com/swift-tutorial-corelocation-and-region-monitoring-in-ios-8/ for this.

Answer (score -1):

I got this error because i did not start the Bluetooth.
So... do not forget to start your Bluetooth ;)